# How to update translation yaml files without deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I have a rails project with multiple languages within I18n and several translation ymls in config/locales/ directory.

Since it is necessary to update the text in these yaml files regularly, I have to deploy very often just for updating the text. I would love a possibility to update yaml files without deploy.

I know, that I could move the texts to db, but this would be way too much overhead for me and if there is another possibility, I definitely would prefer that. Perhaps with a gem, so that editors of the project could update the text by themselves?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**
After some reasearch, there were two possible ways.

1. Copycopter as mentioned below. But I haven't tested this possibility due to separate hosting. Which led me to...
2. http://www.localeapp.com
   It works just out of the box, is very unobtrusive and is great for editing and translating locales on the fly. In production mode, you just have to reload I18n to see changes. During beta-stage, localeapp is completely free of charge.

Comment: Give [Loco](http://localise.biz/) a try too. Not purely for Rails, but you can pull down YML files via the API whenever you need.

Comment: @agieche - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> After some reasearch, there were two possible ways.
>
> 1. Copycopter as mentioned below. But I haven't tested this possibility due to separate hosting. Which led me to...
> 2. http://www.localeapp.com It works just out of the box, is very unobtrusive and is great for editing and translating locales on the
>      fly. In production mode, you just have to reload I18n to see changes.
>      During beta-stage, localeapp is completely free of charge.

~ answer per [agieche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729273/agieche)